# Блоги о C++ и Python

Tags: python, c++

Предлагаю поделиться блогами/сайтами/прочими ресурсами, которые вы постоянно читайте и просматривайте.

C++:

- [Алена С++](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com)
- [Распутывая нити](http://mdf-i.blogspot.com)
- [Программирование - это просто!](http://easy-coding.blogspot.com)
- [Deepen C++](http://deepencpp.blogspot.com)
- [highly professional scums](http://blog.gamedeff.com)
- [Как сломать мозг?](http://brainslugs.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 1):

Для одноразового прочтения - [**C++ FAQ**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/), сразу же после него [**С++ FQA.**](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/)

В свое время неплохо завис на [**InsideCPP,**](http://insidecpp.ru/) раздел *"Арт"* вполне сравним с *"Ководством"* сами-знаете-кого.

Answer (score 0):

Я постоянно сижу на http://www.gamedev.ru. Он не о C++, но большинство из пользователей пишут на нём. В разделе "Общие" уже накопилось, наверное, много тем по C++. И на вопросы по нему там отвечают, только не так, как на ХэшКоде - если вопрос повторяется, то они отправляют в Google и дают ссылки, а здесь на них тупо отвечают.

Comment: Заглядываю туда частенько)